# How do I play audio on clicking a button in an Android app built using PhoneGap/Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm building a basic soundboard-like app which has a few buttons that play sounds. I'm using PhoneGap/Cordova and I'm using the PhoneGap Build service to compile the code to APK. At first, I was using simple HTML5 `<audio>` tags which worked fine in the desktop browser as well as the Android browser, but when packaged into the PhoneGap app, no sounds were being played.

I looked around and saw some mentions of having to use the Media API in PhoneGap instead of standard HTML5 audio, so I switched to that with the following code changes.

I have the following function in place:

```
function doPlay(soundId) {
  var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+soundId+".mp3",
    function() {
      navigator.notification.alert('Success!', alertDismissed);
    },
    function(err) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error!', alertDismissed);
  });
  my_media.play();
}
```

Each button has an `onclick` handler similar to this...

```
onclick="doPlay('sound1');"
```

The files are in the same directory as the `index.html`, called `sound1.mp3`, `sound2.mp3` and so on. And the function `alertDismissed()` has also been defined, but it's empty.

However, it still does not work. There is no sound on click. There is no `'Success'` or `'Error'` message either. Yes, I've got `notification` and `media` permissions requested.

I'm quite stumped here. Any ideas?

*Update:* As suggested by @simon-macdonald, I put a full path to the local files ("/android_asset/www/"), but that still hasn't gotten the app to work. No sound, no error/success alerts. :-(

Answer (score 3):

The path to you files is not correct. You want to do:

```
var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/" + soundId+".mp3",
function() {
  navigator.notification.alert('Success!', alertDismissed);
},
function(err) {
navigator.notification.alert('Error!', alertDismissed);
});
my_media.play();
```

Check out my mini tutorial.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2011/05/using-media-class-in-phonegap.html

Comment: I had a feeling it would be about this, so I excitedly put in this path, but I'm still not getting the sound. Nor am I getting the success/failure alerts. There's something else I'm not doing right. Is it of any relevance that I'm not using Eclipse here? It's just plain text editors and zipping and uploading to Build.

Comment: Well, I know this code works for me. Are you sure your sound files are getting packaged in build? Also, what do you see in "adb logcat" when you test your app? There are usually errors in there that point to the root cause of things.

Comment: I gave up Android development and went back to the web.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling your problem is not related to the code you've written, but just maybe you have forgotten to include the cordova javascript file in your head section.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
```

Best of luck.