# JqueryMobile disable clicks in page except links/buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm doing a Cordova app but whenever I click somewhere in the view(page) the `Click` sound is played.

Moreover, when clicking it seems that the whole page is selected / deselected as on top of the screen a white line appears.

How can I disable user clicking anywhere else except actual links/buttons?

Answer (score 0):

For Android:

1. make setSoundEffectsEnable(false) in Cordovawebview
2. do some play on oncliks like this: [How do I play audio on clicking a button in an Android app built using PhoneGap/Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297193/how-do-i-play-audio-on-clicking-a-button-in-an-android-app-built-using-phonegap)